# How to measure the amount of data transmitted by my MPI program?

Tags: profiling, mpi, monitoring, tcpdump

I'm experimenting my distributed clustering algorithm (implemented with MPI) on 24 computers that I set up as a cluster using BCCD (Bootable Cluster CD) that can be downloaded at http://bccd.net/.

I've written a batch program to run my experiment that consists in running my algorithm several times varying the number of nodes and the size of the input data.

I want to know the amount of data used in the MPI communications for each run of my algorithm so I can see how the amount of data changes when varying the previous mentioned parameters. And I want to do all this automatically using a batch program.

Someone told me to use tcpdump, but I found some difficulties in this approach.

First, I don't know how to call tcpdump in my batch program (which is written in C++ using the command system for making calls) before each run of my algorithm, since tcpdump requires another terminal to run in parallel with my application. And I can't run tcpdump in another computer since the network uses a switch. So I need to run it on the master node.

Second, I saw the traffic with tcpdump while my experiment was going on and I couldn't figure out what was the port used by MPI. It seems to use many ports. I wanted to know that for filtering the packages.

Third, I tried capturing whole packages and saving it to a file using tcpdump and in a few seconds the file was 3,5MB. But my whole experiment takes 2 days. So the final log file will be huge if I follow this approach.

The ideal approach would be to capture just the size field in the header of the packages and sum this up to obtain the total amount of data transmitted. In that way the logfile would be much smaller than if I were capturing the whole package. But I don't know how to do it.

Another restriction is that I don't have access to the computer disc. So I only have the RAM and my 4GB USB Flash drive. So I can't have huge logfiles.

I have already thought about using some MPI tracing or profiling tool such as those mentioned at http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=perftools. I have only tested Sun Performance Analyzer until now. The problem is that I guess it will be difficult to install those tools on BCCD and maybe even impossible. In addtion to that, this tool will make my experiment take longer to end, sice it adds overhead. But if someone is familiar with BCCD and think it is a good choice to use one of those tools, so please let me know.

Hope someone have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Implementations like tcpdump won't work if there are multi-core nodes which use shard memory to communicate, anyway.

Using something like [MPE](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/perfvis/download/index.htm) is almost certainly the way to go.   Those tools add very little overhead, and some overhead is always going to be necessary if you want to count messages.   You can use mpitrace to write out every MPI call, and parse the resulting text file yourself.   By the way, note that MPE is explicitly discussed on the [bccd website](http://www.bccd.net/ver3/wiki/index.php/Debugging_with_MPE).  MPICH2 comes with MPE built in, but it can be compiled for any implementation.  I've only found a very modest overhead for MPE.

[IPM](http://ipm-hpc.sourceforge.net/) is another nice tool that does counting of messages and sizes; you should be able either [parse the XML output](http://ipm-hpc.sourceforge.net/implementation.html), or use the postprocessing tools and just manually integrate the [graphs](http://ipm-hpc.sourceforge.net/examples/ex1/#lb) (say either bytes_rx/bytes_tx by rank, or the message buffer size/count graph).  The overhead for IPM is even less than for MPE, and mostly comes after the program's finished running to do the file I/O.

If you were really super worried about the overhead with either of these approaches, you could always write your own MPI wrappers using the [profiling interface](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node233.htm) that wrapped MPI_Send, MPI_Recv, etc, and just counted # of bytes sent and recieved for each process, and output only that total at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check these possibilities.

Comment: The profiling interface is probably the most direct way to get the information you are looking for.  It is also possible that the specific MPI implementation already provides a report of the total message sizes that are exchanged.